Rails generator lookup policy is not working while overriding rails built in generator
I am trying to override rails controller generator. inside my rails app i have created file at location lib/generators/controller_generator.rb .
  class ControllerGenerator < Rails::Generators::NamedBase
    def hello
      puts "hello"
    end
  end

when i am running command rails g controller test --pretend from terminal then i am expecting to print hello message but instead of this actual rails built in controller is getting invoked and it is creating below files.
  create  app/controllers/test_controller.rb
  invoke  erb
  create    app/views/test
  invoke  helper
  create    app/helpers/test_helper.rb
  invoke    test_unit

About output is not expected as per rails guide lookup path doc https://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#generator-resolution . As per doc below are the lookup paths rails will follow in my case.
rails/generators/controller/controller_generator.rb
generators/controller/controller_generator.rb
rails/generators/controller_generator.rb
generators/controller_generator.rb

my file is present in lib/generators/controller_generator.rb location which is matching with with lookup path generators/controller_generator.rb.
My question is why built in controller generator is getting executed instead of my own controller generator?

Just for a sanity check is lib on $LOAD_PATH? You can try it with $LOAD_PATH.include?(Rails.root.join('lib').to_s)

Maybe I am misreading the docs but it appears that you are going about this incorrectly, when it says the lookup path starts at "rails/generators/controller/controller_generator.rb" I am pretty sure it means Here so it will never get to your generator. If you want to override a builtin generator the instructions can be found in the Overriding Rails Generators section.

@engineersmnky did some digging and Rails only has the resource_controller generator option which is used for rails g resource and the scaffold_controller option for rails g scaffold. The option for the the rails g controller generator is missing. Also the example with the helper in the guide is broken as the helper option only takes a boolean. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Generators.html

Are you sure you need to override the generator class and not just the template?

@max lib path is in $LOAD_PATH .

@engineersmnky - i am able to override controller generator if i am putting my file at location  Rails.root.to_s/lib/rails/generators/controller/controller_generator.rb or  Rails.root.to_s/lib/generators/controller/controller_generator.rb
But i am not sure why overriding is not working when i am putting file in location Rails.root.to_s/lib/rails/generators/controller_generator.rb or Rails.root.to_s/lib/generators/controller_generator.rb

my analysis after few experiment is that lookup logic is as below..
first check in rails application directory in following paths
rails/generators/controller/controller_generator.rb
generators/controller/controller_generator.rb
if not found then check in gems directory for same paths..
if still not found then check in rails application directory in paths
rails/generators/controller_generator.rb
generators/controller_generator.rb
if still not found then check for same path in gems directory....
if still not found then raise error...

@max rails g controller is valid. See: Rails::Command::GenerateCommand#perform, Rails::Generators::invoke and Rails::Generators::ControllerGenerator

The docs do appear to be correct in the precedence order
rails/generators/controller/controller_generator.rb
generators/controller/controller_generator.rb
rails/generators/controller_generator.rb
generators/controller_generator.rb

Your issue is that right now your controller is 4th in line, generators/controller_generator.rb, and rails has one 1st(ish) in line, rails/generators/controller/controller_generator.rb, technically this is rails/generators/rails/controller/controller_generator.rb (see the namespacing explanation below).
This is also why as you pointed out using either lib/rails/generators/controller/controller_generator.rb or lib/generators/controller/controller_generator.rb (this one is a little weird because it has to do with the way rails looks up namespacing) does work because you are jumping in front of the rails generator.
TL;DR
Based on some trial and error it appears that built in rails named generators will take preference over generators in "lib/generators".
Meaning:

"lib/generators/controller_generator.rb" will not load as a generator; but
"lib/generators/example_generator.rb" will

If you place the same controller generator in "lib/rails/generators/controller/controller_generator.rb" this class will load, as will "lib/controller/controller_generator.rb"
This appears to have to do with the way Rails::Generators namespace lookup works. For Example:
With the following directory structure:

"lib/generators/controller_generator.rb"
"lib/generators/example_generator.rb"

The relevant namespaces are:
{
    ["rails:controller", Rails::Generators::ControllerGenerator]
    ["example", ExampleGenerator]
}

However if we change this to:

"lib/rails/generators/controller/controller_generator.rb"
"lib/generators/example_generator.rb"

The relevant namespaces becomes:
{
    ["rails:controller", Rails::Generators::ControllerGenerator]
    ["controller", ControllerGenerator]
    ["example", ExampleGenerator]
}

It appears this is caused by the fact that the lookup process will return after the first valid path (Source) is found and "rails/generators" is given precedent in the lookup_paths:
def lookup_paths # :doc:
  @lookup_paths ||= %w( rails/generators generators )
end

You can also see this preference in methods like file_lookup_paths, which impacts lookup! (called in printing_commands and public_namespaces)
How does this work with the CLI
Under the first configuration rails g controller XXX will try to look up 'controller' in the namespaces and finding none will move on to 'rails:controller'.
Under the second configuration when you run rails g controller XXX it will lookup the 'controller' namespace and use your generator, if you were to run rails g rails:controller XXX accordingly it will lookup the 'rails:controller' namespace and use that generator.

Thanks will check..
after few trail I think lookup logic is as follow and easy to understand. first check in rails application directory in following paths rails/generators/controller/controller_generator.rb generators/controller/controller_generator.rb if not found then check in gems directory for same paths.. if still not found then check in rails application directory in paths rails/generators/controller_generator.rb generators/controller_generator.rb if still not found then check for same path in gems directory.... if still not found then raise error...

@user2274074 it is actually a lot more basic than that. The command simply calls require path where path is simply a loop of the 4 directories listed. This then relies on the basic functionality of require which will use the $LOAD_PATH directories in order. Since lib will be one of the first entries in $LOAD_PATH it will actually try the application first but based on the order specified in the question.

for experiment purpose i created generators/test_unit/model/model_generator.rb file and from rails deleted railties/lib/rails/generators/test_unit/model/model_generator.rb .. i am getting error as cannot load such file. what i dont understand is why code from my rails app i.e generators/test_unit/model/model_generator.rb  is not executed .  i dont understand purpose of this line https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/92591ebd54e044ff3f3b9d802fe65f69cb7e34f2/railties/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb#L47 . if i remove this line then my generator is getting invoked.. any idea?

@user2274074 how are you trying to run that? rails g test_unit:model?
